# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'ModelMetaNames' object has no attribute 'AUTHOR_NAME' when executing it in Jupyter Notebook on IBM Watson Studio

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I am following a tutorial and this step shouldn't give any errors but I stumbled upon this unexpected problem. What's going wrong here? Here is the code block:

```
model_props = {client.repository.ModelMetaNames.AUTHOR_NAME: "IBM", 
           client.repository.ModelMetaNames.NAME: "Heart Failure Prediction Model"}
published_model = client.repository.store_model(model=model_rf, pipeline=pipeline_rf, 
meta_props=model_props, training_data=train_data)
```

Error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 model_props = {client.repository.ModelMetaNames.AUTHOR_NAME: "IBM", 
      2                client.repository.ModelMetaNames.NAME: "Heart Failure Prediction Model"}
      3 published_model = client.repository.store_model(model=model_rf, pipeline=pipeline_rf, meta_props=model_props, training_data=train_data)

AttributeError: 'ModelMetaNames' object has no attribute 'AUTHOR_NAME'

Answer (score 0):

See this example and you'll understand what is happening:

```
>>> a = "mykeyname"
>>> {a:"my value"}
{'mykeyname': 'my value'}
```

So you are trying to use value from `client.repository.ModelMetaNames.AUTHOR_NAME`as key in your dictionary. But such attribute doesn't exists in your model.

If you want to set variable in a object or class, you can simply do:

```
client.repository.ModelMetaNames.AUTHOR_NAME = "IBM"
```

Or if you want to have dictionary object:

```
props = {"AUTHOR_NAME": "IBM", "OTHERKEY": "Something else"}
```

Comment: from watson_machine_learning_client import WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient
client = WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient(wml_credentials) - client does have these attributes as I have used them in other machine learning projects. I tried writing the exact same statements which ran successfully in other Jupyter notebooks but they're all giving the same error.

Comment: You can see all methods and attributes available on that model by saying `dir(client.repository.ModelMetaNames)` in Python console. I don't know why that code works somewhere else, but error message is very clear. `AttributeError: 'ModelMetaNames' object has no attribute 'AUTHOR_NAME'` .  Would you give a example of expected `model_props` dictionary.

Comment: But according to the list, 'NAME' is available, so I committed the 'AUTHOR_NAME' line and entered only 'NAME' line into model_props. I'm getting another error: MissingMetaProp: Missing meta_prop with name: 'type'.

Comment: Also, check out this blog https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-custom_libs_tensorflow.html and scroll down and you'll find a ton of such attributes being used which don't exist in that list.